# changing id in chain of responsibility c++ Qt

Tags: c++, qt, tcp, chain-of-responsibility

I have to do an online game but i'm experimenting some trouble with my chain of responsibility.
The point is that the "int level" a every step of my chain is changing. I mount up the chain in a TcpClient class contructor, every thing work fine when I test in the same constructor but outside the level is totally different.
I brought you some code :

- Parser.cpp

```
Parser *Parser::setNext(Parser *next)
{
    this->next = next;
    return (this->next);
}

void Parser::message(QString msg, int id)
{
    qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO;
    qDebug() << "message lvl " << level << "id : " << id;
    qDebug() << "message lvl " << level  << "msg : " << msg;
    if (id <= this->level)
        this->writeMessage(msg);
    else if (this->next != nullptr)
        this->next->message(msg, id);
}
                    //LaucherParser

LaunchParser::LaunchParser(int lvl)
{
    this->level = lvl;
    this->next = nullptr;
}

void LaunchParser::writeMessage(QString msg)
{
    qDebug() << "msg launch parser:" << msg;
    emit launchGame();
}
```

- TcpClient.cpp

```
TcpClient::TcpClient(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent),
    parsers()
{

    ErrorParser parser(0);
    EmailParser parser2(1);
    LaunchParser parser3(2);
    parser.setNext(&parser2);
    parser2.setNext(&parser3);

    parsers["error"] = &parser;
    parsers["email"] = &parser2;
    parsers["launch"] = &parser3;

    connect(parsers["launch"], SIGNAL(launchGame()),    this, SLOT(startGame()));

    parsers["error"]->message("Game Starting now", 2);  // Traverse toute la chaine de commande

}

void TcpClient::readyRead()
{
    qDebug() << "Reading...";
    QByteArray data =  socket->readAll();
    qDebug() << data;
    Command command = analyse(data);
    qDebug() << "command msg : " << command.msg;
    qDebug() << "command id : " << command.id;
    parsers["error"]->message(command.msg, command.id);
}

void TcpClient::startGame()
{   // ceci est un SLOT
    qDebug() << "Le signal est ok";
}

Command TcpClient::analyse(QByteArray data)
{
    QTextCodec *codec = QTextCodec::codecForName("KOI8-R");
    QString string = codec->toUnicode(data);

    QString codeString = string;
    QString msg = string;

    codeString.truncate(2);
    int id = codeString.toInt();
    msg.remove(0, 3);

    Command result = {id,msg};
    return result;
}
```

And My server send :

```
void ServerLounge::sendGame(QTcpSocket *client )
{
    qDebug() << "Game starting for :" << client->socketDescriptor();
    client->write( "02 launch");
    client->waitForBytesWritten(3000);
}
```

Here is what i get, you can see the level changing.
[client debug on the left, server on the right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NERWq.png)

Comment: Surely you can condense this code a *lot*. Please read [mcve].

Comment: In your `TcpClient` constructor you initialize the `parsers` data member using the addresses of various locally scoped variables which then go out of scope leaving you with dangling references.  That's undefined behaviour.

Comment: Sorry for the bad post.Thanks for the answer, I managed it.